# Adding more than 1 id using rails check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, parameters

I'm new to RoR. Well, new to programming in general.
I want to pass multiple ids from first view to second view but, only the ids that I select using the check_box_tag.

---------- First view -------------------

**Name:**

```
<%= form_tag(method: "post") do %>

<%= check_box_tag("camp", params[:id]) %>

<%= submit_tag("Add to comparison cart") %>
```

------------- Controller ---------------

def compare

```
@camps = Camp.find(params[:id])
```

end

---------- Second view ----------------

```
<%= @camps.name %>
```

Problem:
When I'm routed to the second view it only saves the latest "camp" I checked.

Question:
How can I save multiple camps to the second view?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is Camp.find() only returns a single object, whereas you obviously need to return multiple objects.

There may be an equivalent to .find() that can find and return multiple objects, but I have not used it so I do not know what it would be called. If it exists it would be an ideal solution.

An alternative would be to create an array and then use repeated Camp.find() calls to fill that array. Something like (apologies for pseudocode, do not have time to test it out):

```
@camps = []
for each check box
  @camps.add(camps.find(params[:id])) if checkbox is checked
end
```

(I am assuming you can add a to arrays in Ruby, am still new myself...)

Comment: Thanks Zild. I tried applying the same logic but it kept returning just one id.  I think it has something to do with the what is being temporarily stored in the param.
This is what my rails server is returning: 
"compare"=>"2", "commit"=>"Add to comparison cart", "method"=>"post", "id"=>"2"}
  Camp Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "camps".* FROM "camps" WHERE "camps"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]

Comment: Do you have multiple forms, each with a separate checkbox and a separate submit tag? If so, wouldn't this only ever fire off one ID at a time?  Perhaps a single form and submit tag, with multiple checkboxes would work better?

Comment: Im only using one form and one check box but, you do have a point about using multiple checkboxes. I'll try to see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand how you plan to offer users the option to compare multiple products whilst only offering one checkbox. Unless this checkbox appears on an individual product's page and it is an option to add items (one page at a time) to a comparison view? In that case, I am definitely feeling out of my depth!

Comment: Yes, that correct. It's in on an individual template page and it appears on the page of every product. Sort of how a "add to shopping cart" works. It's just not saving the products. When I got to the comparison view. Thats okay Zild, I appreciate your help though!

Comment: I cannot speak for the "Rails way", but the way I would try to handle this (bearing in mind I have never done anything like this in Rails) is to have a parameter that you pass between pages that contains an array of compare items (those which were previously selected). Or rather their unique IDs. Then with each relevant form submission perform a check to see whether you should add the current item to that list. Then when you wish to use that list of items just iterate through the list. Make sense? (Sorry if this is something you already figured out...)